# why "_dir.yml" file does not work in "Navigation" in nuxt-content?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I was reading [Navigation part](https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/displaying/navigation) of nuxt-content docs. I could not understand what is the actual purpose of that? In some part of this docs, it says:

> the navigation also allows you to configure directory nodes via **_dir.yml** files

I could not understand what that means. Does it mean that the for example "title" of the page could be defined in the `_dir.yml` file? If that is true, it does not work for me.

I created `content/new-dir` directory in my project. Inside that, I created `new-md.md` and `_dir.yml` files. Here are the contents of these two files:

> `_dir.yml` file:

```
title: 'My awesome directory'
navigation.icon: ''
```

> `new-md.md` file:

```
# welcome
```

If what the docs says is true, the title of the url like `http://localhost:3000/new-dir/new-md` in my browser must be `My awesome directory`, but it is `welcome`. Why that happens? Do I misunderstand the concept and usage of `Navigation`?